# How do I open an iphone app and tap an item hands free?

Tags: ios, siri, shortcuts-app

I'm trying to find the best way to open an 3rd-party iOS radio app, and tap a preset station to play, hands free (I drive a ton).

I'm picturing "Siri, ~shortcut name~".

-I'm new to ios Shortcuts, but I can't seem to find a "tap" function and google says there isn't one. So all I can do so far is just open the app.
-When I looked at accessibility controls I noticed the radio app's preset doesn't have any sort of designation I could access it from either.
-I can almost achieve this with a voice control custom gesture, but it needs a prior second command to go to home screen first, and also I don't want Voice Control running continuously. Nor do I want the complication of turning voice control on and off every time I use the command.
-I can do an assistive touch custom gesture, but that's not hands free, and also needs home screen first.
-I don't see any way in Shortcuts to call up either type of custom gesture.

Ideas please?

Comment: Theoretically, this doesn't need a shortcut at all. "Hey Siri. Play [xyz] radio station" [or 'tune into'] should work… but good luck. I ask it for 'Radio X' [a popular UK indie station] & get Ed Sheeran…X. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/ipha562cea63/ios

Comment: @Tetsujin , thank you for replying.  I have edited the question to clarify.  I'm using a 3rd party app.  The iOS music app will not play the station correctly.